# What is the performance difference between running Docker on Windows versus Linux?

Tags: docker, containers

We are looking at containerizing some of our applications and servers (Red Hat servers to be specific), and there was an idea to run Docker on Windows instead of Linux so the end user has an easier time operating the system. The first thought I had was "what is the performance difference between using Docker in Windows vs in Linux?"

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference between **linux** containers running on Windows, Linux, or Mac will depend entirely upon how much ram you allocate to the Docker Daemon.  The difference should not be noticeable.  Additionally, you will be able to take advantage of the Alpine base image (~5 Mb) for small, compact containers.

If you need to run IIS in your container, then you should look at **windows** containers.  The disadvantage is that the containers will be significantly larger in size, and you will lose cross-platform compatibility.  [Docker windows containers](https://www.docker.com/products/windows-containers).